# Not able to send post parameter by request builder

Tags: java, rest, gwt, http-post

It is opening new window but not passing Post parameters to new window using GWT.

```
final RequestBuilder rb = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, encodedUrl);
rb.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
rb.setRequestData(json);
Request response = rb.sendRequest(json.toString(), new RequestCallback() {
    public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {}
    public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
        Window.open(rb.getUrl(), postTarget, postWinFeatures);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show the expected network traffic, vs what you are actually seeing? For example how are you reading a post parameter on the server, and how should it be included in this code sample? For example, your Content-Type says that it will be a form, url-encoded, but your code suggests that the content is actually JSON, not url-encoded at all?

Comment: POST parameter? open a new window? content-type form-urlencoded? It is really confusing. IF you are sending a request, this definitively has no relation to open-a-window, so please clarify that. Then, you can send JSON or urlencoded, not both! If you are sending a form you should use an actual form. If you want to send JSON, then use "application/json", and do not repeat the requestData call, both the send first argument and the setRequestData does the same, so choose one.

Answer (score 0):

FormPanel form = new FormPanel(target);

```
                form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
                form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_URLENCODED);
                Hidden params0 = new Hidden("dds", "xyz");
                Hidden params1 = new Hidden("sdsdsd", "sdsd");
                Hidden params2 = new Hidden("sdsd", "sdsdd");

                FlowPanel panel = new FlowPanel();
                panel.add(params0);
                panel.add(params1);
                panel.add(params2);

                form.add(panel);
                //form.add(buildPostURLParameter());
                form.setAction(buildPostURL());
                RootPanel.get().add(form);
                form.submit();
```